# How do I edit my fontsize programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-textattributes

This problem is more complicated than the title.
I have a java class which maps on the values from the server. Now I am setting the textsize programmatically, as follows:

```
headerButton.setTextSize(Application.getAppResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.manage_markets_text));
```

and setting manage_markets_text in dimensions as 15sp for layout, for values-xlarge: 20sp and for values-large dimension 18sp. Now, For the xlarge tablet it is getting 20sp as desired, However for htcone phone it is mapping on some large font size which I don't even know where it gets from (appears to be like 40-50sp). Now I changed the code, to accept getDimension instead of Pizelsize and I still have the same issue. if I set settextsize(r.dimen.manage_market_text) ,it displays blank page. How do I go about fixing this issue? Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would want to set this in your XML.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:textSize="@dimen/manage_market_text"
    ...
/>
```

Also, using values-xlarge is a bit old fashioned. According to

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You should format your files such more like values-sw600dp.

To answer your original question simply write

```
Resources res = this.getResources();
headerButton.setTextSize(res.getDimension(R.dimen.manage_market_text))
```

That should do the trick